# rails - autocomplete textfield gem with location

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, autocomplete, rubygems

I already have a plugin which I use 'city-state', https://github.com/loureirorg/city-state
The gem mentioned above I use it to prepopulate state list based on country selected and then prepopulate city list based on state selected, its quite old style.

I am building an application where on the frontpage I need to have a textfield with autocomplete feature, just like say airbnb. 
So, the objective is that if the user start typing city, country name it should autofill or country, city name etc.

I am curious to know if there is any gem for that?

Dont understand why its downvoted, if I posted something wrong then do correct me, but downvoting is such a unprofessional behavior.

Answer (score 2):

This is more Javascript functionality on the front end. You'd want to use an autocomplete library like one of these

https://twitter.github.io/typeahead.js/

http://selectize.github.io/selectize.js/

You need to use some type of JSON data too feed it with the cities, for that you could get out of the CS gem you're already using.

Comment: I of course have the intent of using ajax autocomplete functionality for this, but even for that I would need a dataset and all, but was looking for more of a gem or maybe even a solution to how to get such dataset.

Comment: @mad_programmer the CS gem should suffice I think. Just request for the states based on the country after it's selected.